# Usage of がった behind the past tense: くすぐったがった。

Tags: grammar

I know that it's possible to use がる in combination with い-adjectives, but what does it mean after the past tense of another verb?

Full sentence:

> 彼は彼女が泣くまでくすぐったがった。

---

**Update:** Actually I just typed "He tickled her until she cried." into DeepL and that sentence was the result.

Comment: Could you double-check you've copied the sentence correctly?

Comment: @chocolate - 彼がくすぐったがりすぎて、それを見ていた彼女がなぜか泣いたとか。

Comment: くすぐったい is an adjective.  So, がる works as it usually does in such a context.

Comment: I think you should've clarified which verb you mean by 'after the past tense of another verb'.

Comment: @sundowner My guess is that the OP like me originally parsed the verb as くすぐる and he expected to see くすぐりがる.  And if you use an online dictionary, you can easily miss other forms you wouldn't miss in a Japanese dictionary.

Comment: I suspect this is a misuse or typo for くすぐりたがる.

Comment: @aguijonazo That would make a lot more sense to me.  As it currently is, I can make some sense of it, but it seems a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @A.Ellett - Yes, it would be surreal. He would have to be tickled by someone AND be able to stop his reaction to it and put on a straight face while still being tickled when someone, his tickler or a spectator, starts crying...

Comment: `Actually I just typed "He tickled her until she cried." into DeepL and that sentence was the result.` -- @Celestial, You should have included this info in your question.

Comment: I don't think there is anything inherently wrong with questions that arise from machine translation in an absolute sense, but context should always be provided. You should be suspicious of machine translation to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to try to summarize here what's in the comments.

くすぐったい is an adjective.

がる has the sense of "putting on an appearance" or "pretending".  From this sense, we can parse

> くすぐったがる

as putting on an appearance of being ticklish.  But, my sense is also that this could then be understood as "acting as if he were being tickled".

彼女 witnessed this.  And that brought her to tears.

So the sentence would mean something like,

> He acted like he was being tickled to the point that she cried.

Considering what @aguijonazo wrote in the comments to the question, this could perhaps also be construed as

> He acted [so much] like he was being tickled that she cried.

Where "acted **so much** like he [was being] tickled" corresponds to  くすぐったがり**すぎて**.

I would imagine this is one of those situations where folks tease back and forth so much that you're both laughing and perhaps so hard you start crying.

Comment: ん‥？　「くすぐったがった」の主語は彼ですが。。

Comment: @chocolate "He seemed ticklish".  Is that what you're suggesting?  Then I guess I too am not sure what to make of 彼女が泣くまで if he's the one who's ticklish.

Comment: 「彼はくすぐったがる」というのは彼はくすぐったく振る舞っているという意味なので彼女はただそれを見ていて泣いているだけです。

Comment: 「くすぐったがる」は「くすぐったい＋がる」ではないわけですか？ Yeah, I better say this in English.  So, you're saying くすぐったがる is not くすぐったい＋がる?

Comment: @shinku I think you should post an answer.  The only issue is then the very one the OP raised.  How do you parse くすぐったがる?  "He seemed so ticklish that it brought her to tears".  I guess I would need more context to understand that.  I can understand being tickled so much you cry.  I can understand starting to cry because you don't want to be tickled.  But crying because someone else looks ticklish sounds weird.  What am I getting wrong?

Comment: It is the adjective+がる, がる means to act in a certain way, 欲しがる=act in a way that shows desire. Using the same principle くすぐったがる=act in a way as if being tickled. Since it's to the point that the girl is crying then she is watching him. Seeing something funny makes you laugh, so she is probably laughing to the point of crying.

Comment: @shinku Responding to me in Japanese is fine.  But me responding back in Japanese is just going to sound horrendous.

Comment: Actually I just typed "He tickled her until she cried." into DeepL and that sentence was the result.

Comment: @CelestialDragon That makes deepL the one at fault here, that also explains why you brought up the "past tense of a verb" albeit knowing the adjective+がる rule. Removing がった gives the desired meaning.

Comment: @shinku I didn't plug into DeepL.  That's someone else.  I completely agree with what you're saying about the DeepL analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Just posting an answer to see if my understanding of *tickle/ticklish* is correct.

First, just be aware of the following forms:

- くすぐる : to tickle
- くすぐった = くすぐる + た : tickled ★１
- くすぐったい : (adj) [ticklish](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ticklish)?
- くすぐったがる = くすぐったい + がる : (someone) to feel ticklish
- くすぐったがった = くすぐったがる + た : felt ticklish ★２

I'm not sure *ticklish* is the right word for it - at least くすぐったい does not have to imply uncomfortable (as *ticklish* in the dictionary). Usually the most common reaction of the person who feels くすぐったい is to laugh.

The subject(topic?) of くすぐったい is often the part of the body that makes the tickled person laugh.

- 脇腹{わきばら}はくすぐったくない : Tickling my side does not make me laugh.

The subject of くすぐったがる is always a person and basically means *to react to the tickle*. I don't go into details for the general がる meaning.

Thus the sentence in question means *Till she cries, he laughed by the tickle.* (★２ above), which requires some imagination to understand what's going on. On the other hand, *He tickled her till she cried* is 彼は彼女を泣くまでくすぐった (★１ above).

Comment: This is a great answer and fills in some of my doubts.

Comment: Something else that I think is noteworthy is that some words like 恥ずかしい really have two different meanings from the point of view of English: "embarassed" vs "embarassing".  I think it's something similar with くすぐったい, "to be ticklish" vs "to be tickled".